# How to use new access token on other page using server side authentication - PODIO API

Tags: podio

I've already authenticated my App on 1 php page using `GET['code']` method and I received the refresh token code and saved it.

Now I want to authenticate on other page on the same domain. So I what I did is I created other php page that check if I'm authenticated or not using `is_authenticated()` function if not I request a new access token using CURL to API endpoint `"https://podio.com/oauth/token"`. I received the access code and tried to authenticate with it using `authenticate_with_authorization_code($code, REDIRECT_URI)` but I'm getting error  **Uncaught PodioInvalidGrantError: "Sorry, your OAuth code is invalid."**. Please let me know what step I'm missing.

```
<?php
require ('podio/podio_lib/PodioAPI.php');
include ('sessionpodio.php');
define("REDIRECT_URI", 'http://domainname.com/pagename.php');

$refreshtoken = "my_refresh_token";
$client_id = "xxxxx";
$client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$param = "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id={$client_id}&client_secret= 
{$client_secret}&refresh_token={$refreshtoken}";
Podio::setup($client_id, $client_secret, array(
  "session_manager" => "PodioBrowserSession"
));


if (!Podio::is_authenticated()) {

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://podio.com/oauth/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www- 
form-urlencoded'));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$decoded_r = json_decode($server_output,true);
$code = $decoded_r["access_token"];


echo "<pre>".print_r($decoded_r, true)."</pre><br/>";
var_dump($code);

if ($code !== "") {
Podio::authenticate_with_authorization_code($code, REDIRECT_URI);   
}   
}

 elseif (Podio::is_authenticated()) {

  // User already has an active session. You can make API calls here:
    print "You were already authenticated and no authentication is needed. 
<br/>";
    var_dump($_SESSION);
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you check if your return url for the second page is valid?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've already resolved this using Podio Session manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved issue using [Podio Session Manager](http://podio.github.io/podio-php/sessions/), manual authentication using  expired access token and refresh token is not needed as library will handle it automatically, see Podio Session Manager for more information.